# Scan text file in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file in US-ASCII which contains a single, long line.  The text items that I need to access are separated by a varying number of spaces, like this:

```
metadata1 attrib1     metadata2 attrib2   attrib2a trackstart attrib1   attrib2   trackstart attrib1 atrib2 attrib3
```

The file can have a maximum of 99 'track' entries and will take little memory.

**What I need to do**

I have to extract these entries into an in-memory structure that I can iterate over, access values, and count items.  For instance I need to get the number of 'tracks' (by counting the 'trackstart's in the above example, and also add the attributes for each track into a structure like `object.track1.attribute1`.

**What I have tried**

I used a Scanner to read in the file and step through the text entries.  This seems to work fine.  I then created nested HashMaps, like:

```
HashMap<String, String> overallMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); // contains the tracks map and some other metadata
HashMap<String, Map> tracks = new HashMap<String, Map>();  // contains a map of all tracks
HashMap<String, String> track = new HashMap<String, String>(); // contains an individual track
```

But the problem is that (I think) HashMaps won't let me count the keys (so I can't, say, get the number of 'tracks' in my text file).  I suspect I'll run into other issues with this data structure.

**Questions**

1. In this case, is a Scanner the best way to read in and manipulate the file?
2. What in-memory data structure should I choose?  How can I build up the track list, count the tracks, and access individual attributes in this structure?

Comment: First, you can use `Map.size()` to give you the number of keys in the `Map`. Second, if you are using `Map`s of `Map`s etc then this is usually a sign of "Object Phobia". The fact that you have the concept of a `Track` means you should have a `Track` object that stores its attributes.

Comment: So every track has attributes and metadata objects have attributes and tracks, correct ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi There are a couple of 'metadata' keys with a varying number of values which sit at the root of the entire data structure, but it is primarily made up of 'tracks' which are delimited by 'trackstart' and also contain a varying number of values.  'metedata' objects don't contain tracks. Thanks!

Comment: So its like you have some metadata keys which have some attributes and then some tracks with their own attributes and tracks dont fall under metadata or vice versa ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Exactly!

Comment: Also,do all metadata keys look like - metadata1, metadata2, metadata3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have some metadata objects and some tracks, where each has variable number of attributes, we could have a base class named "MyObjects" to represent each of them

```
public class MyObject implements java.io.Serializable
{
    String name;
    ArrayList attributes;
    public MyObject(String name)
    {
       this.name = name;
    }
    public void addAttribute(String attr)
    {
        this.attributes.add(attr);
    }
}
```

And then have a class MyFile which would represent each file that you read.

```
public class MyFile
{
    MyObject[] metadata;
    MyObject[] track;

    public int check(String s)
    {
        if(s.substring(0,s.length()-1).equals("metadata")) return 0;
        if(s.equals("trackstart")) return 1;
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Then in the main function you could read the file

```
File f = new File(filepath); 
BufferedReader br = new InputStreamReader(f.getInputStream());
String line = "",content = "";
while((line = br.readLine())!=null) content += line;

MyFile myfile = new MyFile();
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(content," ");
int status;
String word = "";
while(t.hasMoreTokens())
{
    word = t.nextToken();
    status = myfile.check(word);

    // add the attributes to the to metadata or tracks

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is an OO language, and you should thus create your own objects rather than only relying on data structures. That will make everything easier, to write, read, and maintain.

So you should have a `Track` class, containing a `List` or `Set` of attributes. The choice depends on if you care about the order of the attributes, and on if you must remove duplicates or not.

The Track class should let you add and get attributes, since that's what you need to do. And since it seems you're only interested in the tracks and not in the other information in the line before the first track, you just need a List of tracks to keep all the tracks.

So the algorithm should be quite simple:

- split the line in tokens
- create an empty `List<Track>`
- iterate through the token

  - if the current token is `trackstart`, then create a new `Track`, and assign this new `Track` instance to the variable `currentTrack`. Add this track to the list of tracks
  - if the current token is anything else, then

    - either `currentTrack` is null, and you should ignore the token
    - or `currentTrack` is not null, and you should add the token as an attribute of the current track by calling `currentTrack.addAttribute(token)`

At the end of the algorithm, you have a `List<Track>` full of Track instances, in the same order as the tracks in the line. And each Track instance has a `List<String>` containing the attributes of the track.